# Change axis labels in ggeffects plot

Tags: ggplot2, plot, glm, lme4

Is there any way to change legends/axis labels/tick marks in the plot( ) function for visualising model predictions in ggeffects? I can't find any mention of this in the function documentation, but it seems like such a bizarre thing to leave out ... ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ggeffects package, but if it just extends ggplot2 the usual functions should work, which would be documented in ggplot2's documentation.

Comment: Could we have a [mcve] please? Can you give a more specific example of what you want to change?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to user [teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand) - I hadn't realised you could add additional elements to `ggeffects::plot()` using as you would in `ggplot( )` - adding `+ labs(title = "New title")` etc worked!